# Need help finding cause of high CPU with Win10 System and compressed memory

Tags: cpu

I've looked at many messages about this problem and see there are a multitude of reasons. Elsewhere on this site a user suggested using Windows toolkit's Windows Performance Recorder to create a trace file and Windows Performance Analyzer to determine cause of high CPU in this process. I've recorded a couple minutes of no programs running with WPR and viewed the results in WPA. It is clear that there is a CPU hog, but I'm not finding a way to identify that particular thread.

Anybody want to look at the file and see if they can help me? Here's a link - https://www.dropbox.com/sh/hsh9c0t241vxbtq/AADrncUoI6LksByYmXYFid8ia?dl=0

Thanks.

Comment: The folder is empty.  Please take the time to edit your question, then after you fix the url, test to make sure you can access it without being logged into DropBox.